# Change about routers between Magento 2.0.0-rc and Magento 2.0.0-rc2

Tags: magento2

I have a module with routers have frontName as "ticket". It working in Magento version 2.0.0-rc. But when i install this module in Magento version 2.0.0-rc2, i request to this routers and browser return "404 Page".

How to fix this routers ?

Thanks for advice.

This is very strange, because my module working normally with Magento 2.0.0-rc.

***EDIT***

My code in below.

**app/code/Demo/Ticket/etc/frontend/routers.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="ticket" frontName="ticket">
            <module name="Demo_Ticket" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/Demo/Ticket/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framewo rk/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Demo_Ticket" setup_version="1.0.0">
      <sequence>
         <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
      </sequence>
   </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Demo/Ticket/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
   namespace Demo\Ticket\Controller\Index;

   class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {
        public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ){
           parent::__construct($context);
        }

       public function execute()
       {
           echo "Event Ticket";
       }
   }
```

**app/code/Demo/Ticket/registration.php**

```
<?php
   /**
    * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */

   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
      'Demo_Ticket',
       __DIR__
    );
```

Comment: Can you post the your code to see how you register the new route?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have `registration.php` in your module. See [official guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/component-registration.html) about registering your module in Magento 2. If that does not help, check out [this issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2311) (which prevents installation of non-composer modules).

Comment: Yes, i have registration.php in my module, so i can run in Magento 2.0.0 RC

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `Your/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml` looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="yourmodule" frontName="ticket">
            <module name="Your_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And you have a matching `Your/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php` file like this:

```
<?php
namespace Your\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        die('tickets');
    }
}
```

That should display "tickets" if you navigate to http://www.example.com/ticket, make sure to adjust the Directory names to match your URL structure but that's the basics of it.

Your `registration.php` file should look something like this:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Your_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

If all that fails try running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` or clearing the caches.

Comment: You can view again my code. Where is the issue ?

Comment: That's strange, is the rest of the component functionality broken as well or is it just the routes? I'm wondering if the module is being ignored by Magento.

Comment: My module decrated in `app/etc/config.php` and after run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, it have create table in database.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to http://www.example.com/index.php/ticket ? Could be that the permalink rewrite isn't working or enabled.

Comment: I try add new file in`Magento/Catalog` module have path as `app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Index/Demo.php` , it working normally with routers as `catalog/index/demo`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. It was a failure in autoloader, *empty* declaration in composer.json

The problem only was in Magento 2.0.0-rc2 and is solved in newer versions.

in RC2, composer.json looks like:

```
"psr-0": {
        "_empty_": "app/code/"
   },
```

and it should be:

```
"psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
   },
```

see this issue to resolve your problem
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2381